# Multiple alignment

Tags: align

In the following piece of code

```
\begin{align*}
[x \mapsto s]x &= s \\
[x \mapsto s]y &= y \qquad \text{als } y\neq x \\
[x \mapsto s](\la{y}t_1) &= \la{y}[x \mapsto s]t_1 \qquad \text{als } y \neq x \text{ en   } y \not \in FV(s) \\
[x \mapsto s](t_1 \; t_2)&= ([x \mapsto s]t_1)\;([x \mapsto s]t_2)
\end{align*}
```

I am currently only aligning on the = sign. Is it however also possible to align on more than one place in the environment? I would also like the \text to be aligned, as wel as the begining of each new line.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Multiple alignment points with no gap between expressions is obtained using the `alignat` environment from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). The following MWE illustrates that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  &[x \mapsto s]x &&= s && \\
  &[x \mapsto s]y &&= y \qquad &&\text{als } y\neq x \\
  &[x \mapsto s](\lambda(y)t_1) &&= \lambda(y)[x \mapsto s]t_1 \qquad &&\text{als } y \neq x \text{ en   } y \not \in FV(s) \\
  &[x \mapsto s](t_1 \; t_2)&&= ([x \mapsto s]t_1)\;([x \mapsto s]t_2) &&
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

I've taken the liberty to convert the unknown `\la{<arg>}` macro to `\lambda(<arg>)`.

Consider reading Herbert's [`mathmode` document](//mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). It illustrates the various "alignment environments" of `amsmath` clearly. Specifically, see section **25 `align` environments**, p 43 onward.

Comment: great! will give it a read, also my apologies for the unknown macro, you converted it correctly,

Comment: One doesn't even need `alignat`: the simple `align` can do the same, but it adds spacing as it thinks correct, which might not be what the user wants.

Comment: egreg: could you elaborate? Because spacing would be nice, I currently forced it using \qquad...

Comment: @codd: See [@_barbarabeeton's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56650/5764).

Comment: @Servaes: Thanks. The [`mathmode` stub](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) on CTAN puts the "package" down as *obsolete* (hence the link change).

Comment: Servaes' link is also dead now. I think [this](http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) is what @Werner probably linked originally, but as they said, it's filed under obsolete. Does that mean this answer is no longer valid?

Comment: @Empiromancer: The [math mode document](//mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) is just not being updated and therefore it's considered obsolete, but the content in it is still valid.

Answer (score 48):

using just `align` would be done like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  [x \mapsto s]x &= s \\
  [x \mapsto s]y &= y &&\text{als } y\neq x \\
  [x \mapsto s](\lambda(y)t_1) &= \lambda(y)[x \mapsto s]t_1 &&\text{als } y \neq x \text{ en   } y \not \in FV(s) \\
  [x \mapsto s](t_1 \; t_2) &= (x \mapsto s]t_1)\;([x \mapsto s]t_2)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

this gives the following result:

[image: display with multiple alignment points]

Comment: when I try this, significant white space is inserted in front of the `&&` character. Any idea why?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer -- `align` assumes "columns" of equations, so it separates them by a wider space to make them distinct.  The answer using `alignat` is probably more appropriate for the situation described in this question.

Answer (score 9):

The above suggestions, e.g., `alignat`, all produce a reference number for each line. If you need to reference the entire block by one number, use [`alignedat`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Other_environments) in an `equation` environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% see other answer
\begin{alignat}{3}
  &[x \mapsto s]x &&= s && \\
  &[x \mapsto s]y &&= y \qquad &&\text{als } y\neq x \\
  &[x \mapsto s](\lambda(y)t_1) &&= \lambda(y)[x \mapsto s]t_1 \qquad &&\text{als } y \neq x \text{ en   } y \not \in FV(s) \\
  &[x \mapsto s](t_1 \; t_2)&&= ([x \mapsto s]t_1)\;([x \mapsto s]t_2) &&
\end{alignat}


\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    &[x \mapsto s]x &&= s && \\
    &[x \mapsto s]y &&= y \qquad &&\text{als } y\neq x \\
    &[x \mapsto s](\lambda(y)t_1) &&= \lambda(y)[x \mapsto s]t_1 \qquad &&\text{als } y \neq x \text{ en   } y \not \in FV(s) \\
    &[x \mapsto s](t_1 \; t_2)&&= ([x \mapsto s]t_1)\;([x \mapsto s]t_2) &&
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]