# How to align at multiple positions when each line is a single equation?

Tags: align

I have equations of which each one has two equal signs.
I want to align those equations at both positions of equal signs, like:

```
a =  b + c = d
e = 2b + c = f
```

By using two "&"s, each line will be seperated, which is not what I want.
Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Here is one possible duplicate: [Multiple alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56627/5764)