# how to get two align point with split equations

Tags: align, split

I have this equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \alpha &= \frac{1}{100} S \sqrt{2g} = 2.2444e^{-05} \ [m^\frac52/s]\\
    \beta &= \pi r^2 = 0.0079 \ [m^2]\\
    \gamma &= \frac{2 \pi r}{tan(\theta)} = 0.1814 \ [m] \\
    \delta &= \frac{\pi}{(tan(\theta))^2} = 1.0472
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

and would like to add a second align point on the second '=' symbol. Is there a way to do that?

Thank

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please complete your given code snippet to be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing and we can see, if you use math related packages like `amsmath` etc.

Comment: Split only supports a single `&` per line. Use `aligned` instead, or `alignat/alignedat` as mentioned below. I tend to always use `aligned` in situations like this, and will only switch to `split` when I need the specific features it provides.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first post, I will write all the code on the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `alignat` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        \alpha&=\frac{1}{100} S \sqrt{2g} &&=2.2444e^{-05} \ [m^\frac52/s]\\
        \beta&=\pi r^2&&=0.0079 \ [m^2]\\
        \gamma&=\frac{2 \pi r}{tan(\theta)}&&=0.1814 \ [m]\\
        \delta&=\frac{\pi}{(tan(\theta))^2}&&=1.0472
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *tan* should use a backslash to be typeset upright.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple questions on the same topic. I am taking the answer of Werner from the question [Multiple alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56627/multiple-alignment)

Multiple alignment points with no gap between expressions is obtained using the `alignat` environment from amsmath.

With that, the code changes to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \alpha &= \frac{1}{100} S \sqrt{2g} = 2.2444e^{-05} \ [m^\frac52/s]\\
    \beta &= \pi r^2 = 0.0079 \ [m^2]\\
    \gamma &= \frac{2 \pi r}{tan(\theta)} = 0.1814 \ [m] \\
    \delta &= \frac{\pi}{(tan(\theta))^2} = 1.0472
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\begin{alignat}{2}
    \alpha &= \frac{1}{100} S \sqrt{2g} &&= 2.2444e^{-05} \ [m^\frac52/s] \notag\\
    \beta &= \pi r^2 &&= 0.0079 \ [m^2]\\
    \gamma &= \frac{2 \pi r}{tan(\theta)} &&= 0.1814 \ [m] \notag\\
    \delta &= \frac{\pi}{(tan(\theta))^2} &&= 1.0472 \notag
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why to use `{3}` in `\begin{alignat}{3}`? I reckon `{2}` alignments should be also fine.

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah - Yes you are right. I have updated the answer.